# WordPress user role changes automatically

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

The role of one of my users who has admin role will be changed automatically a few times every day and I have to manually update it again. I'm not sure if it's a plug-in problem but this is the only admin user that the role will be updated automatically. Is there anyway that I can see the logs to find what's wrong? Is there any code that I can put on function.php to change the role to admin for that user of the role was changed as a temporarily fix?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with User Role Editor and Admin Menu Editor. Worth disabling these if you have either of them installed?